# Compiler update for Carthage project

Tags: swift2, xcode7.2

I got a project, which is built with Carthage and uses swift2.0. I am trying to run the project, but encountered this issue:

> Module file was created by a newer version of the compiler.

After struggling for about 1 hour, I found that this error occurs when I trying to build Carthage project in newer version of Xcode. My version is 7.2 and the project was built using a newer compiler version.

How can I build this project in Xcode 7.2? I don't want revert my xcode version.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading my xcode version to 7.3, the problem has fixed.